# Easy way to reset scroll view position

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have horizontal UICollectionView, and i want to reset it X position. I tried following:

```
 let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 1)

 self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition(rawValue: 0), animated: false)
```

However it not work, i got an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x61000002d040> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}'
```

How to scroll collection view to start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work if there are no items

```
 self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition(rawValue: 0), animated: false)
```

Use (Objective C):

```
CGPoint topOffest = CGPointMake(0,-self.collectionView.contentInset.top);
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:topOffest animated:YES];
```

Use (Swift):

```
let topOffest:CGPoint = CGPoint(0,-self.collectionView.contentInset.top)
collectionView?.setContentOffset(topOffest, animated: true)
```

Comment: thanks but i like answer to be represented in Swift

Comment: let topOffest:CGPoint = CGPoint(0,-self.collectionView.contentInset.top)
        collectionView?.setContentOffset(topOffest, animated: true)

Answer (score 1):

```
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: [0,5], at:.centeredHorizantally, animated: false)
```

0 represents the Section Number 0

5 represents Cell no 5

Comment: self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: index, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizantally, animated: false)